# How to run a module from the command line with options?

Tags: python, pytest

Modules in python can be run from the pipeline [with the `-m` option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#command-line):

```
python -m pytest
```

This runs pytest with the advantage that [the current directory is added to sys.path](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/usage.html).
Now I want to run `pytest` with the `-verbose` option, but surrounding it with quotes/ticks does not work:

```
python -m pytest -verbose
python -m "pytest -verbose"
python -m 'pytest -verbose'
python -m `pytest -verbose`
```

How do I use options when running pytest with python from the CLI?

EDIT: The comment from Dinari solved it, I mistakenly used `-verbose` instead of `--verbose`

Comment: `python -m pytest --verbose`  should work, or `-v` but not `-verbose`

Comment: @Dinari you are right, I mistakenly did `-verbose` instead of `--verbose`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
python -m pytest --verbose instead
```

Notice the double dash instead of the single dash.

You use the single dash when using the short version usually -v ,however, here you use —verbose as you are using the long version.